# How to add new UITextField to a custom UITableViewCell when return key pressed with animation

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

For example in iphone contacts application,in add address cell, when user typing in the "street" text field , another text field with place holder "street" is add below the current text field with animation, how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your IBAction method, create the text field, set the frame and add to the cell:

```
CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);

UITextfield *textView = [[UITextfield alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

[cell addSubview:textView];
```

A couple things to keep in mind:

Make sure to remove the textView in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` if a cell id dequeued and you don't need the field. Setting the field's tag can help with finding it again. If you do need the field, you will need to added it in this method as well.

You may need to resize the height and report correct heights in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Depending on what you are doing, you may just want to add another cell with `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` as there would be less cell state to manage. Cell state can get very tricky very fast if you aren't careful.

Comment: ya thanks for idea i will try this ... thanks for replay.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this code:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    CGRect frame = textField.frame;
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + frame.size.height + 5;//5 is space between two teftFields
    UITextField *newTextField =[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    textField.placeholder = @"street";
    [[textField superview] addSubview:newTextField];

    return YES;
}
```

For animation thinggy try tweaking around:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)
                 animations:^{
                     ￼
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     ￼
                 }];
```

Cheers.

Comment: @Shan At your service sir. :) i would like you to have look here. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

You can call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to add a new row with animation. And in the new row, you specify the cell with text field with place holder "street".

Comment: i am having a single custom cell within that i want to add new text field with animation ..

Answer (score 0):

You can make an IBAction with the code you need to add the new UITextField and then in your xib, link the action with your initial textField using "Did End On Exit". That will allow you to execute the new method when the user presses return.